# Multiple relationship between two objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I define multiple relationships between two objects in Ember? For example A user can be either a staff or a customer the differentiator is the userType property. If a customer buys a product, the product object need to have link to the customer that bought it and the staff that facilitated the sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic version of a data model that would suffice for what you have described. You can adapt it for your needs. I have used the app global haven't specified whether you are using `ember-cli`.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    userType: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
    orderedBy: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    facilitatedBy: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

A useful tool for creating a first pass of a data model when you are unsure of the ember syntax is [Ember Data Model Maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/). You can use it to see how you should set up your model definitions and then modify them later.

Comment: Just what I need and some more for mentioning Ember Data Model Maker, such a neat tool. Thanks Oren :D